# Why make two functions? (one is non-const and the other is const)

Tags: c++, function, constants

I'm relatively new to C++. I was looking into the source code of Box2D to learn how professional people manage their code and found this kind of pairs quite a lot:

```
inline b2Body* b2World::GetBodyList()
{
    return m_bodyList;
}

inline const b2Body* b2World::GetBodyList() const
{
    return m_bodyList;
}
```

Questions that popped into my mind is, how do we know which function that we called? What's the reasoning for this kind of pair?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The non-`const` version cannot be called on a `const b2World`; note that the return types of the methods are different. Try running

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
    void greet() { std::cout << "Hello, world!\n"; }
    void greet() const { std::cout << "Hello, const world!\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.greet();

    Foo const &fooref(foo);
    fooref.greet();
}
```

See also the [C++ FAQ Lite on `const`-correctness](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.12).

Comment: Ahh I see. Thanks for the concise explanation and neat example!

Comment: sorry, but this example is bad and missleading and has nothing to do with return types. `const` operator after function names indicates, that the code cannot modify the internals of struct. Maybe, compiler chooses the second function when working with const reference, but the result is the same as no modification occures there. Having those 2 functions doesnt make sence at all in the real world

Comment: @Ulterior: it's intended to show which member function will be called on a mutable `Foo`, and which on a `Foo const &`.

Comment: Foo const foo2; foo2.greet(); // will also call the const function (tested this in VS2010)

Answer (score 1):

The reason to have both is when you want to allow to kinds of accesses to m_bodyList: Anyone who has a const instance of your class can get a read-only (const) m_bodyList and anyone who has a non-const instance of the class can get a non-const m_bodyList, which they can modify.